# C# PictureBox неполное отображение содержимого

Tags: c#

На форме WinForms создано 4  PictureBox, в цикле для каждого контрола устанавливается image из Dictionary где ключом является путь к файлу картинки:

```
foreach( KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in openWith )
    {
        Image image = Image.FromFile(kvp.key); 
        switch (kvp.key )
        {
         case "1.bmp":
             pictureBox1.Image = image;
             break;
         case "2.bmp":
             pictureBox2.Image = image;
             break;
         case "3.bmp":
             pictureBox3.Image = image;
             break;
         case "4.bmp":
             pictureBox4.Image = image;
             break;
         default:
             Console.WriteLine("Default case");
             break;
        }     
    }
```

Однако после выполнения цикла, не все  PictureBox(ы) отображаются с заполненынми картинками. Спасибо заранее за помощь большое

Comment: Вы уверены, что все ветки `case` были задействованы? Если да, то во всех ли случаях есть изображение в `image`?

Comment: Абсолютно уверен, содержимое коллекции заполнено верно, а image берется из каждого элемента коллекции. 4 элемента коллекции = 4 pictureBox

Comment: Тогда странно такое поведение... Я бы порекомендовал вам поставить точку останова на строке получения изображения из файла. Убедитесь на всех шагах, действительно ли есть изображение и действительно ли вы попали в каждую ветку `case`. Пока только советы, так как предоставленных данных мало для того, чтобы дать ответ.

Comment: У вас в `kvp.key` лежит просто имя файла во всех элементах коллекции `openWith`, нигде не забрался еще и путь? Всегда оно совпадает с одним из значений в `case`?

Comment: Да, очень странно, ставил точку останова. Поля контролов числятся как заполненными imagam(и) и отобрпажаются на форме, однако если запускаем без отладки - картина выше. Все в UI потоке происходит

Comment: В  key лежит полный путь к файлу, проверял

Comment: Если у вас в `key` лежит полный путь, то не удивительно, что `pictureBox` не заполняются. То что в `key` должно полностью совпасть с тем, что в `case`. Если не совпадет - то в блок не попадет. Покажите скриншот, где будет видно, что в `key`

Comment: Нет, прошу прощения, там не полный путь, а просто имя файла

Comment: Замените `Console.WriteLine("Default case");` на `MessageBox.Show(kvp.key);` и увидете, что не проходит

Comment: Извините, это опечатка,

Comment: Также, у меня есть подозрения, что у вас просто перекрываются изображения одно другим и вы думаете, что что-то не загружено. Если после добавления `MessageBox` не было всплывающих сообщений с именами файлов, тогда изображения находятся поверх друг друга. Я так думаю. Дополните вопрос скриншотом

Comment: Я пришлю скриншот вечерком, не делал